# Python: Can you set cpu counts with multiprocessing Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cpu

With `multiprocessing.Pool`, there are code samples in the tutorials  where you can set number of processes with cpu counts. Can you set the number of cpu's with the `multiprocessing.Process` method.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

Comment: Actually your program can easily be modified to use `multiprocessing.Pool` - so you do not have to take care about CPU count explicitly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `Process` represents only one process which uses only one CPU (if you dont use threads) - it is up to you to create as many `Process`es as you need.

This means that you have to create as many `Process`es as you have CPUs to use all of them (possibly -1 if you are doing things in the main process)

You can read the number of CPUs with [multiprocessing.cpu_count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count)

Comment: Actually you cannot set the count of CPUs that are used with `multiprocessing` - all you can do is create as many processes as there are CPUs and hope the OS distributes them well among the CPUs.

Comment: @merlin You can't set the number of `cpu's` using pool, you can only set the number of Processes.

Comment: You would have to do that explicitly eg by keeping track of the number of created processes in the main process and checking when about to create a new one.

Comment: @Merlin `Process` only starts one process (per call), so there is nothing to set.